# not able to find views directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8081;
require('./db/conn');
const path = require("path");

const static_path  = path.join(__dirname,"../public");
const template_path = path.join(__dirname,"../template/views");
console.log(template_path);

app.set("views",template_path);
app.set("view engine","hbs");

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("succesfully port");
})
```

It's show me this error:

Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\template\views"
at Function.render (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\src\app.js:15:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

[this is my folder structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O961O.png)

Comment: I'm curious does my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You type wrong folder name.
Error message have told your express look for views in `"D:\node and express\dhainik\mernbackend\template\views"`.
The folder name is `templates` not `template` in your folder structure screenshot.

```js
// original
const template_path = path.join(__dirname,"../template/views");

// you should use this.
const template_path = path.join(__dirname,"../templates/views");
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer is really helpful for me. I never imagine this type of error.

Comment: You’re welcome. You could mark this as answer to let other people know you’ve fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure but what I think you have to do is because your views are in folders you have to navigate out of it. So basically like this:

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("././index");
})
```

also to enable static folder in express you have to do:

```
app.use(express.static('{static folders name}'));
```

not sure if this all will work but try it tell me if the console gives you a new message